# How could factordb apply the p-1-method on this number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

The following partial factorization

http://factordb.com/index.php?id=1100000001285565404

was used by factordb to prove this number ($\ 32^{2133}+4^{2133}+1\ $) to be prime.

http://factordb.com/index.php?query=32%5E2133%2B4%5E2133%2B1

What confuses me : I only know a variant of the p-1-method , where $n-1=FG$ where $F$ is completely factored and we have $F>G$. This is apparently not the case in the given factorization.

> So how could factordb prove the primality with the $p-1$-method ?

Comment: (2^10665+2^4266-2)+3= 3+(2^10665-1)+(2^4266-1) ?